# Why does my ListView managed by a custom CursorAdapter refreshes automatically with new data?

Tags: android, listactivity, android-cursoradapter

I have had this "issue" for sometime on my app and it always bothered me that I didn't understand it's behavior, but never cared about asking why, until now.

I have a `ListView` (implemented through a `ListActivity`) with a custom layout for each list item. With that I have a custom `CursorAdapter` to properly fill all the list item elements (overriding `newView` and `bindView`, the ViewHolder pattern is already guaranteed when doing it like this, refer to: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1057 if needed).

This is the main Activity and there are 2 actions that can update the content of the `ListView`, create a new item or edit a current one. For both, the same activity is used (which adapts itself to the type of action), something like this:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_NOTE_EDITOR_CREATE);
startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_NOTE_EDITOR_EDIT);
```

What actually distinguishes the action type is the intent contents, the `requestCode` is ignored in the sub activity.

Now, the documentation has this to say about the method above:

> When this activity exits, your onActivityResult() method will be
>   called with the given requestCode.

But I'm not using `onActivityResult`. Actually, I'm not doing anything when the sub activity exists (either in create or edit mode). And the behavior I've noticed so far is this:

- **Create:** Almost all the time I return to the main activity, the `ListView` is automatically updated with the new item. However, sometimes, rarely though, the `ListView` is not populated with the new item. I need to destroy the main activity (exiting the app for instance) and recreate it and then the new item will be there.
- **Edit:** I never noticed similar behavior as just described for the create action. So far, the `ListView` was always automatically updated with the new content changes.

My question is, what's happening behind the scenes that makes my `ListView` to automatically update it's contents when I never call `cursor.requery()` nor manually notify of any changes to the content? And why the hell doesn't it work all the time?

Should I maybe force a `cursor.requery()` myself on `onActivityResult`?

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final int ACTIVITY_NOTE_EDITOR_CREATE = 0;

    private NotificationHelper mNotificationHelper;
    private AgendaNotesAdapter mAgendaAdapter;
    private Cursor mAllNotesCursor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mNotificationHelper = Program.getNotificationHelper();

        mAgendaAdapter = new AgendaNotesAdapter(this);
        mAgendaAdapter.open();

        initializeNotesListActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent;

        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.actionbar_item_new_note:
                intent = NoteEditorMainActivity.createIntent(this);
                startActivityForResult(intent, ACTIVITY_NOTE_EDITOR_CREATE);
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void initializeNotesListActivity() {
        mAllNotesCursor = mAgendaAdapter.fetchAllNotes();
        startManagingCursor(mAllNotesCursor);

        NotesListAdapter notesAdapter = new NotesListAdapter(this, mAllNotesCursor,
                mNotificationHelper, mAgendaAdapter);

        setListAdapter(notesAdapter);
    }

}
```

P.S: I know about CursorLoader and it's something in the roadmap, but I don't have time to deal with such code rewrites for the time being. Just thought I'd let you know. For now, I just need to know what is happening with my current code.

Comment: Post the code for your main `ListActivity` or at least the `onCreate` method.

Comment: Question updated with the relevant code.

Comment: Not worth posting as an answer, but maybe you can call that initializeNotesListAdapter() class in onActivityResult(). It won't serve as an end-all solution (it resets the position of the ListView which can be annoying for users), it can at least help you see if the list adds the new item in this instance.

Comment: @JMRboosties The problem is that I don't have a way to test that, 99% of the time the new item is added to the list. Like I said below in one of the comments, maybe I should just forget about that tiny problem, until it becomes a real issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `startManagingCursor()` means that when the activity is stopped, the `Cursor` is deactivated, and when the activity is restarted, the `Cursor` is requeried.

> Should I maybe force a cursor.requery() myself on onActivityResult?

This should automatically occur for your managed `Cursor`.

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious like the `startManagingCursor` thing. I'm just wondering why sometimes it doesn't seem to requery the cursor. But it really happens very rarely, so rarely that I have forgotten about that issue until I saw it once the other way, hasn't happened anymore since that time. Maybe I should just forget it, until it becomes a real issue.